# Add row to table in C# error (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, dataset

I have problem with these code. I want to add a row to a dataset, but I have this error " An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property " for a sampleDataSet.bar_of_4Row. I tried to make it static but it did not work. I tried to do it like in this tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NaplnenieDB
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            sampleDataSet.bar_of_4Row newBarRow = sampleDataSet.bar_of_4.Newbar_of_4Row();
            newBarRow.bar = "RRRR";
            newBarRow.first = "R";
            sampleDataSet.bar_of_4.Addbar_of_4Row(newBarRow);



        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a an object of the class `sampleDataSet.bar_of_4` in order to call the method `Newbar_of_4Row()` on it.

Try this:

```
var myDataSet= new sampleDataSet();
sampleDataSet.bar_of_4Row newBarRow = myDataSet.bar_of_4.Newbar_of_4Row();
newBarRow.bar = "RRRR";
newBarRow.first = "R";
myDataSet.bar_of_4.Addbar_of_4Row(newBarRow);
```

Try to stick to the convention that class names start with an uppercase and variable names start with a lowercase. That will make this all less confusing.

Comment: i forgot to mention, that sampleDataSet is DataSet imported from another project to Data Sources of this project, so i want to add some rows in this project and in another project only select data from tables.

Answer (score 0):

This will create a new DataTable, DataRow(s), DataColumn(s) and allow you to populate the values.

Hope this helps.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // create table 
        DataTable sampleDataTable = new DataTable("Bar_of_4");
        // create row
        DataRow sampleDataRow = sampleDataTable.NewRow();
        // create column
        DataColumn column;

        // set info about the first column
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        column.ColumnName = "bar";
        sampleDataTable.Columns.Add(column);

        // set info about the second column
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        column.ColumnName = "first";
        sampleDataTable.Columns.Add(column);

        // add column data to the first row
        sampleDataRow["bar"] = "RRRR";
        sampleDataRow["first"] = "R";
        sampleDataTable.Rows.Add(sampleDataRow);

        // add column data to the second row
        sampleDataRow = sampleDataTable.NewRow();
        sampleDataRow["bar"] = "SSSS";
        sampleDataRow["first"] = "S";
        sampleDataTable.Rows.Add(sampleDataRow);


        // loop through each row and display the column info
        foreach (DataRow row in sampleDataTable.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}",row["bar"],row["first"]));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress any key to continue");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```